# email marked as spam even with DKIM, SPF and DMARC headers

Tags: email, spam

I've configured a Postfix+Dovecot email server. I took care of `SPF`, `DKIM`, `DMARC` and added appropriate headers to the message. I haven't used the machine for 2 years, so it can't be blacklisted from previous users. For reasons unknown to me, my email still gets marked as spam by gmail. This is the source of the mail, as seen by gmail. I stripped away some of the very long unique ids, to make it more readable.

```
Delivered-To: targetemailaddress@gmail.com
Received: by IPv6_here with SMTP id s12csp565193ios;
        Fri, 1 Feb 2019 07:45:41 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: someuniquestring
X-Received: by 2002:a63:6c48:: with SMTP id h69mr34585542pgc.139.1549035941764;
        Fri, 01 Feb 2019 07:45:41 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1549035941; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=verylongstringhere==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:message-id:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:reply-to
         :from:sender:subject:to:dkim-signature:dkim-filter;
        bh=somelongstring=;
        b=verylongstringhere2==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mycustomdomain.com header.s=201901 header.b=qCd3nM9G;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@mycustomdomain.com designates IPv6_here as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=support@mycustomdomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mycustomdomain.com
Return-Path: <support@mycustomdomain.com>
Received: from mycustomdomain.com (mycustomdomain.com. [IPv6_here])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id k91si7726103pld.283.2019.02.01.07.45.41
        for <targetemailaddress@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 01 Feb 2019 07:45:41 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of support@mycustomdomain.com designates IPv6_here as permitted sender) client-ip=IPv6_here;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mycustomdomain.com header.s=201901 header.b=qCd3nM9G;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@mycustomdomain.com designates IPv6_here as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=support@mycustomdomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mycustomdomain.com
Received: by mycustomdomain.com (Postfix, from userid 48)
    id 743B95C469; Fri,  1 Feb 2019 16:46:12 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 mycustomdomain.com 743B95C469
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mycustomdomain.com;
    s=201901; t=1549035972;
    bh=somelongstring=;
    h=To:Subject:From:Reply-To:Date:From;
    b=vverylongstringhere3==
To: targetemailaddress@gmail.com
Subject: Update on the files
Sender: Support Team <support@mycustomdomain.com>
From: Support Team <support@mycustomdomain.com>
Reply-To: Support Team <support@mycustomdomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Message-Id: <20190201154612.743B95C469@mycustomdomain.com>
Date: Fri,  1 Feb 2019 16:46:12 +0100 (CET)

You start as a beginner and then you make it to the end.
```

I ask for double check on what to do, so that my mails won't automatically be marked as spam. I strongly feel that my problem has to do with inadequate headers. What headers should I add or change?

**EDIT:**

Blacklist test results are all OK.

Comment: I would start by putting your server's IP address into here to see if it's blacklisted: https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: Does Postfix send the email from an email account?

Comment: Has the domain itself been in use for a long time?

Comment: @tshimkus Not sure what you mean.. I am using PHP's `mail` function to send mail.

Comment: @MrWhite It's been online for about 6 months

Comment: I ran into the same issue with PHP's mail function a few months back. I think Gmail and some other mail servers want emails to originate from an actual SMTP account. I was able to avoid the spam filters by switching to PHPMailer, where I included an email account and password. This routed the mail through the SMTP server and resolved my spam issues.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for stopping by. What do you mean by "originate from an actual SMTP account"? As far as my limited knowledge goes, all info about who and how an email got sent is in the headers. Can you share headers of a mail sent with PHPMailer?